# How can I resolve a class with 3rd party generic interface by string using autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, autofac

There are different classes registered in autofac with same generic interface but using different class models. What I need is to resolve the class with string without knowing the class model. I am not sure if it can easily be achieved. Any suggestions please.

I am using a console app and I don't know the class model as we receive a string. I have registered all class in the start class but I want to resolve the class without knowing the class model. I don't want to use if else to say if string == "something" then resolve this else if resolve this. I am looking for the best practice.

```
public TestModel1 { }
public TestModel2 { }

public interface ICalculator<string, T> {}
public Impl1: ICalculator<string, TestModel1> {}
public Impl2: ICalculator<string, TestModel2> {}
```

in Autofac I register like:

```
builder.Register<Impl1>.As<ICalculator<string, TestModel1>>();
builder.Register<Impl2>.As<ICalculator<string, TestModel2>>();
```

in Console app I want to do something like:
container.Resolve by string rather than doing like

```
if (...) {
class = container.resolve<ICalculator<string, TestModel1>>()
} else {
class = container.resolve<ICalculator<string, TestModel2>>()
}
```

I want to be able to do something like in console app:

```
var class = container.resolve<ICalculator>("pass string");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK You can only resolve what you register.  SO you can't get an `ICalculator` from a `ICalculator<string, TestModel2>` because those are two very different interfaces.

Use [Named Services](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-services).  You can either do:

Assuming:

```
public class Impl1 : ICalculator<string, TestModel1> {}
public class Impl2 : ICalculator<string, TestModel1> {}
// Notice these are the same ---------------------^
// If these need to be different use #2 (Below)
```

Register:

```
builder.Register<Impl1>.Named<ICalculator<string, TestModel1>>("pass string1");
builder.Register<Impl2>.Named<ICalculator<string, TestModel1>>("pass string2");
// Notice these are the same ------------------------------^
```

Resolved it via:

```
var r = container.resolve<ICalculator<string, TestModel1>>("pass string2) 
// = Impl2
```

OR 2.

First create a base interface:

```
public interface ICalculator {}
public interface ICalculator<T1, T2> : ICalcuator;

public class Impl1 : ICalculator<string, TestModel1> {}
public class Impl2 : ICalculator<string, TestModel2> {}
```

Register:

```
builder.Register<Impl1>.Named<ICalculator>("pass string1");
builder.Register<Impl2>.Named<ICalculator>("pass string2");
```

Resolved it via"

```
var r = container.resolve<ICalculator>("pass string2) 
// = Impl2
```

You should really consider using scopes to help control the lifetime of your objects if your console app (or real app) is very complex:

```
builder
  .Register<Impl1>
  .Named<ICalculator<string, TestModel1>>("pass string1")
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder
  .Register<Impl2>
  .Named<ICalculator<string, TestModel1>>("pass string2")
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

then

```
using (scope1 = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var r = scope1.Resolve<ICalculator>("pass string1");
  // r would be disposed if it implemented IDisposable
  // before scope1 is `Disposed()`
}
```

> However, the problem I face is that the interface is coming from a library developed by another team.

In that case you could try registering generic, and let the DI know the Generic types at resolution instead of during implementation:

```
// @nuget: Autofac

using System;
using Autofac;

public class Program
{
    private static IContainer _Container;
    public static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder
            .RegisterGeneric(typeof (Impl1<, >))
            .Named("pass string1", typeof (Calculator3rdParty<, >))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder
            .RegisterGeneric(typeof (Impl2<, >))
            .Named("pass string2", typeof (Calculator3rdParty<, >))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        _Container = builder.Build();

        using (var scope = _Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var c3p = scope
                .ResolveNamed<Calculator3rdParty<string, Model1>>("pass string2");
            // specify type at resolve ----------^

            Console.WriteLine(c3p.GetType());
        }
    }
}

public interface Calculator3rdParty<T1, T2>{}

public class Model1{}

public class Model2{}

public class Impl1<T1, T2> : Calculator3rdParty<T1, T2>{}

public class Impl2<T1, T2> : Calculator3rdParty<T1, T2>{}
```

Output:

> Impl2`2[System.String,Model1]

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jmk548)

Comment: Thanks Erik, the second option is a very good solution. However, the problem I face is that the interface is coming from a library developed by another team. We can't just ask them to create an interface as you suggested  just for us. Is there any other solution you can think of?

Comment: @ArashEM Updated per your request.  Please mention in the original question that the interface is from a 3rd Party.

Comment: Thanks @Erik. That looks better but I don't know the class model at that point. What I know is a string value, which based on that I know which model I am going to use. However, I don't want to write 10 if else to resolve the proper one. When I register all of them, is there anyway in Main method I get all registered by that interface and look at metadata to select the one I need? If not, I might ask the other team to add an interface then I use your second solution.

Comment: I decided to create a new interface and use it instead of the one from library. Therefore, I can apply the second solution Erik suggested.